# opening main.axml using visual studio 2013

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, mono

I searched in so many forums and viewed similar subjects here , but none of them worked me . 
please help to fix this error .
I'm using VS 2013 , android sdk 23.0.2 and android mono 4.10 . there is no problem while building and running the progam using emulator . but still i can't edit main.axml file with andorid desinger .
the error shown is :
http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-08/65982611363918318925.png

> the operation couldn't be completed. invalid pointer

Comment: There are a couple open source tools for doing this kind of stuff.  You should check them out.  I want to say phone gap lots of phone gap questions here @ stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem today. after struggling a bit and testing every thing i just found out that the problem is android sdk tools.
**Update it to 24.1.2.** and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Android designer doesn't work on axml. pronounced Zam El  Maybe try one of the MS editors.

Expression Studio , Expression Blend but I woudn't expect too much of the really cool stuff to work on every single device you port your code to.

axml and the android xml layouts are just gorified html so for simple things maybe you can use regular text editor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294525.aspx

Comment: what do you mean by : "Android designer doesn't work on axml." .axml files in android projects can be opened using android designer by default . this is not XAML , it's AXML , android xml which can be edited by android designer . in XAMARIN website have mentioned that you can layout program with android designer in visual studio. http://xamarin.com/visual-studio

Comment: `axml and the android xml layouts are just gorified html` - huh?  They are not even close, except they are text.

Comment: somebody help me , this feature would be so useful for android programming

Comment: @Petter I'm that somebody who tried to help.  I'm danny117 on asp.net so I do know something of MS.  Lets see I think you should visit the windows app store and see if your visual studio is up to date.  Then I would delete and re-instal whatever conversion tool your using.  https://store.xamarin.com/ free you obviously have a free or indie account or you would be in xamarin forumn.  Editing is not supported on your version so dive into the xml like I said.

Comment: @danny117 thank you for trying to help. but i think you did'nt understand my point , maybe because you are not familiar with android programming. in 2014 nobody doesn't waste his time to create xml and edit it in text editors . even if i could'nt use android designer in viusal studio , i'll use droiddraw application for generating axml file not text editors . but having this feature in visual studio would be more helpful

Comment: Good luck getting your visual studio setup.  @Petter I know the don't look at the xml argument.  Last century it was don't look at the xml generated by a web service.   Argumentum ad hominem notus   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gosylvester.demomapmarkeraddanddrag  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gosylvester.bestrides   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gosylvester.hilbilyfashliegt